# when I use the dialog to show a new page, it can be used only once and always show the same thing in the page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Hello this is the first time I'm using dialog. Here is my code:

```
       $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnWscape: true,
        show: "blind",
        width: 800,
        buttons: {
            close: function () {
                alert("close");
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }
        }

    });

    $('p#pp').click(function () {

        //jQuery('#fpoint').dialog();
        //$("#dialog").load("Agrandir.aspx").dialog("open");
        //var tid = $("#Label1").text.toString();
        alert("open");
        //$("#fpoint").dialog("open");
        $("#dialog").load("Agrandir.aspx).dialog("open"); 
        //  window.open("Agrandir.aspx");
    })
```

In the dialog will show a new page, in the page will show an execl. In the parent page there is an dropdownlist, when the button click this.session["id"] will get the value of the selected value, the Agrandir.aspx will use the session. Then click to open a dialog. But the dialog alway shows the same dialog which is created at the first time.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console to indicate that the AJAX call from `load()` failed?

Comment: Maybe adding **cache: false,** ?

Answer (score 2):

Place this script on your pages to prevent jQuery ajax calls from caching their responses.

```
$(function() {
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

**jquery.load()** will cache responses without it.

[See this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) for more information.

Comment: thank you~! It is good. But there is still a problem that I have set a button on the dialog. But it doesn't work. And I type "esc" to close it, then I can't open it again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but you are putting the close event in the buttons option list and you misspelled closeOnEscape. Try:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    show: "blind",
    width: 800,
    buttons: {
        "Close": function () {
            alert("close");
            $(this).dialog("close");

        }
    }

});
```